# How to add custom color to the already existing bootstrap navbars

Tags: css

**I am not able to change the bootstrap5 navbar color to a custom color.
I am not sure why
i want to design a website by relying on the bootstrap with my own custom navbars and topbars**

I tried to add a class to the navbar-custom and setup background color but nothing worked. its dark and the color doesnt change

```css
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-dark navbar-custom"></nav>
```

Comment: Have you looked using your browser's dev tools inspect facility to see exaclty where/who is changing the styles? You may find for example some !important have been added to some styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `bg-dark` class from `nav`.

```css
.navbar-custom{
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-custom">
  <ul><li>Home</li></ul> 
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello Rohit . THis helped. But why is it so. why cant i have a dark coloured navbar. i mean why it doesnt change the colour if it is dark. also if it is bg-dark, then cant i add a class to it and specify my own color

Comment: bg-dark has !important property of CSS which will override all styling under it

Comment: Understood ... thanks a lot rohit. How would we get to know as to what attributes have !important property...only through developer tools???

Comment: Most of Bootstrap classes have !important attached. If you want custom colours, you are better off creating your own custom classes rather than over-writing the Bootstrap defined ones.